# Gluon scattering in AdS

Tags: string-theory, scattering, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft, gluons

In recent years there has been interest in computing scattering amplitudes of (super)gluons in Anti-de Sitter (AdS) space in all kinds of stringy theories in different spacetime dimensions (see for example https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.15830).

What is the reason behind these studies? Why are we interested in computing these quantities? Are there other motivations besides the interest in holographic correlators?

**Edit:** in case it is ambiguous, I do not disregard these studies at all. I just don't know anything about it and I'm genuinely trying to understand what are the important questions in this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm biased of course, but I think we'd be missing out on a lot if holographic correlator results stayed limited to maximally supersymmetric theories. The examples you mention seem to be the most tractable non-maximal holographic CFTs one can possibly have. They describe gluon scattering in the same way that the maximal ones describe graviton scattering.

Identifying pairs of AdS/CFT duals is all well and good. But the feature that gave AdS/CFT such a big impact is that it opened the door to $1/N$ expansions in CFTs more complicated than the vector models that had been studied previously. I.e. those with either a large 'tHooft coupling in the Lagrangian or no Lagrangian at all. For $\mathcal{N} = 4$ SYM, this idea of using gravity to compute $1/N^2$ corrections went from being a [tedious chore](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9912210) to [a pleasure](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.06624) in 2016, so it would be a shame to not try out the technique on a broader set of theories. Especially since "using gravity" is now understood to mean nothing more than imposing a selection rule which limits the number of single trace operators.

Some special properties, well known for $AdS_5 \times S^5$, which you can't get away from by looking at the other two cases with maximal SUSY are:

1. All single trace operators live in short multiplets of the superconformal algebra.
2. The bulk has no open strings / the boundary has no internal global symmetry.

Understanding what happens when these are relaxed has conceptual implications. On the other hand, two special properties which *do* break for $AdS_4 \times S^7$ and $AdS_7 \times S^4$ end up coming *back* if you look at $AdS_5$ backgrounds with half of the maximal SUSY.

1. Hidden conformal symmetry which causes anomalous dimensions at the first few orders to simplify.
2. A one-loop amplitude which seems to only require simultaneous poles in the Mellin variables.

I find this interesting given the number of [rich structures](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.2684) that are known for 4d $\mathcal{N} = 2$ theories. We can also get some motivation by looking at the flat space amplitude literature.

1. These correlators satisfy color-kinematics duality (later extended to a [double copy relation](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.07651) for the 4d case) which one needs gluons to talk about.
2. Even for methods that are general in principle, some have been studied more heavily in gauge theories than they have in gravity since the former are renormalizable in 4d.

Finally this has led to a rare example of a way in which an $\mathcal{N} = 2$ SCFT might be *simpler* than $\mathcal{N} = 4$ SYM. For some calculations that are not particularly deep, it is expected that a spin-1 version of it will run faster than spin-2. But in a [very recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.01016) we found something more surprising in the sphere free energy in one such theory. It's supposed to have a double expansion in $1/N$ and the string coupling $\tau$. But it turns out to really be the sum of two single variable expansions.

Hopefully more results like this will come out soon. But in the long term, I think researchers interested in holographic CFTs should gradually move towards more general / less supersymmetric examples. Even if this doesn't mean computing holographic correlators every time, there should be tools in place for people who might want to do this.

Comment: Thanks Connor, that's what I needed.